# ggplot2 plot of trigonometric function looks jagged

Tags: r, ggplot2

The curves of trigonometric function plotted with ggplot2 looks jagged.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( data.frame( x = c(-0.2,0.2)), aes( x = x)) + 

stat_function( fun = function(x) cos( pi/x)   , geom = "line")
```

Gives this jagged plot:

[image]

But I was expecting a more smooth plot like this:

[image]

Comment: Increase `n`. See `?stat_function`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame( x = c(-2.5,2.5)), aes( x = x)) + 
       stat_function(fun = function(x) ifelse(x!=0, cos(pi/x), 0), 
       geom = "line", n=5000, col='blue')
```

[image]

Comment: Using zero as the limit there hurts. At least use `NA`. (It won't change the plot.)

Comment: Sure we should use NA @Roland